# Applying this PHP function to a Plugin?

Tags: php, function, wordpress

I have found out a way to do this is in WordPress:

Say you post something under a sub-category called "news-sub", which parents category is "news".  By deafult, the wordpress post will get posted under both news and news sub even if you only select it to be posted under the category news-sub. I've found a way for a post to only get posted in its sub category when you select it to be posted in just its sub category.  Here is the code that inserts in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_post_queries' );
function my_post_queries( $query ) {
  // not an admin page and is the main query
  if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){
    if(is_category()){
      add_action('posts_where', 'current_category_only');
    }
  }
}

function current_category_only($where) {
  $current_cat = get_query_var('cat');
  if($current_cat){
    global $wpdb;
    return " AND ( $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN ($current_cat) ) 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' AND ($wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    OR  $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'private')";
  }
  return $where;
}
```

This code works awesome. But, it doesn't work with plugins. For example... I have a plugin that posts thumbnails and titles for your selected category. Say I select it to display only the "news" category.. if I posted something just under just the "news-sub" category, it still gets displayed via the plugin, regardless of my function code I mentioned earlier.  I tried copy and pasting the function code into the plugin, but it didn't work. :(

So, how would I get this function to work with plugins that display categories? Would I modify it and leave it in the functions.php file, would I modify it and copy and paste it into my plugin file or how would I modify it at all?  Any help would be tremendously appreciated! :)

Comment: If anyone needs the code for my plugin that displays category thumbnails, I'll gladfully put it in here via pastebin. :)

Comment: Here is an error I get when I try to insert the function code above into my plugin: "Cannot redeclare my_post_queries() (previously declared in /directory/directory/public_html/directory/wp-content/themes/directory/functions.php:10)" Of course it doesn't actually say "directory". Could this be that I'm trying to call (or "redeclare") the same function twice ? What would be the work around?

Comment: I have a feeling no one will ever be able to crack this. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are describing is absolutely expected. [Categories are hierarchical](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Semantics#Terminology_Related_to_Content), so a parent category is expected to contain the subcategories *and their posts*.

Your `posts_where` filter is trying to change the behavior to be more like tags. But some functions like `get_posts()` [do not run these filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where):

> Certain functions which retrieve posts do not run filters, so the posts_where filter functions you attach will not modify the query. To overcome this, set suppress_filters to false in the argument array passed to the function. The following code sample illustrates this.

```
$posts = get_posts( array( 'suppress_filters' => FALSE ) );
```

It depends on your plugin code if the filter is observed or not, so there is no clean way to rewrite the category logic. You might be better off using tags for the non-hierarchical semantics you seem to need. Or have a look at [custom taxonomies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) which

> are an extremely powerful way to group various items in all sorts of ways.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, it seriously means so much to me since my whole website depends on this one function / code.  Hopefully it's not too late now and you'll never see this... but I found where my plugin retrieves posts.. it does it with the following code:
$myposts =get_posts('numberposts=-1&&category='.$listCatId[1].'&&orderby='.$categoryThumbnailList_OrderType.'&&order='.$categoryThumbnailList_Order); I've tried entering in your surpress_filters code into the get_posts code but nothing has worked. How would I enter in the array code to make it work with the the get_posts code?

Comment: I've been trying for the past 20 minunutes to insert your supress filter false code into my code (listed in this comments section) but nothing has worked :(

Comment: I tried:   get_posts( array( 'suppress_filters' => FALSE ) || 'numberposts=-1&&category='.$listCatId[1].'&&orderby='.$categoryThumbnailList_OrderType.'&&order='.$categoryThumbnailList_Order);

But this did not work unfortunately  :(

Comment: I'm gonna accept this answer because it steared me in the right direction.  I found out about the ability to show posts only by tags, taxonomy, etc... I ended up making the plugin to only display posts with the tag "news", that way I can always decide if I want the plugin to display a post by just entering in the tag.  Thanks a lot man, you definitely helped me out and geared me in the right direction. :)

Comment: Great, semantically it makes much more sense, as tags do not have a hierachy by definition.